# PHP's PDO SQLite Driver is Returning Duplicate Date

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm running PHP 5.4.4 on my server, compiled with `./configure`. I have PDO with the SQLite 3.7.7.1 driver. I've created the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
login (
    id PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
    given_name,
    family_name,
    gender
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
address (
    id,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES login(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
certification (
    id,
    certification,
    certification_expiration,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES login(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And this view.

```
CREATE VIEW "members" AS SELECT
    login.id, login.given_name, login.family_name, login.gender,
    address.street, address.city, address.state, address.zip,
    certification.certification, certification.certification_expiration
FROM
    login, address, certification
WHERE
    login.id = certification.id
    AND
    login.id = address.id
```

I am querying the view like this:

```
<?php   foreach ($sql->query('SELECT * FROM members;') as $row):    ?>
                    <tr>
<?php       foreach ($row as $index => $col): ?>
                        <td><?=$index;?>.<?=$col;?></td>
<?php       endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
<?php   endforeach; ?>
```

And it's producing an output like this.

```
            <tr>
                <td>id.123456789012345678901</td>
                <td>0.123456789012345678901</td>
                <td>given_name.Mark</td>
                <td>1.Mark</td>
                <td>family_name.Tomlin</td>
                <td>2.Tomlin</td>
                <td>gender.Male</td>
                <td>3.Male</td>
                <td>street.1 Some Lane</td>
                <td>4.1 Some Lane</td>
                <td>city.Anywhere</td>
                <td>5.Anywhere</td>
                <td>state.NY</td>
                <td>6.NY</td>
                <td>zip.12345</td>
                <td>7.12345</td>
                <td>certification.AEMT-P</td>
                <td>8.AEMT-P</td>
                <td>certification_expiration.2015-07-31</td>
                <td>9.2015-07-31</td>
            </tr>
```

I'd like to know, why it's giving me `id.` and `0.`, and `given_name.` and `1.`, and is there anything I can do the filter this behavior out from the query? I'd like to get just `id.` or just `0.` but not both types.

Comment: You can start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php `PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it

```
$sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hat tip, [biziclop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260007/biziclop) for the assist.